# drawing a line following an object in unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello I am using this code to draw a line that follows an object

```
Debug.DrawLine(new Vector3(gameObject.transform.position.x,     gameObject.transform.position.y, gameObject.transform.position.z),
        new Vector3(prevPosition_x, prevPosition_y, prevPosition_z), Color.red,1.0f);

    prevPosition_x = gameObject.transform.position.x;
    prevPosition_y = gameObject.transform.position.y;
    prevPosition_z = gameObject.transform.position.z;
```

However this doesnt draw in a build. Does anyone know how to do this without using the built in line or trail renderers.  I know it can be done with gl but dont have a clue how to do this.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Similar to Xerosigma's answer I've had luck creating trails from cylinder's.  The code is a bit involved because you have to manually handle updating the UV's, vertices, and triangles but it allows for shader-conscious trails.

Answer (score 1):

I do believe Debug.DrawLine only works in the Scene Editor.

There are several ways you can draw lines, GL is definitely one of them. There is also [Vectrosity](http://starscenesoftware.com/vectrosity.html).

Alas, you can do it yourself with some effort by generating your own line mesh and moving the vertices around.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As Xerosigma said, Debug.DrawLine only works in Editor, because it's purpose is to debug scripts, not provide visualization for users. Another problem is that this way, you'll only create lines that will render one frame, and previous to current position will only differ by one frame. You, on the other hand, probably want the trail not to be dependent on framerate.

I think that you'll find [TrailRenderer](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/TrailRenderer.html) component in Unity fitting for your situation. I've used it in [one of my hobbie projects](https://github.com/golergka/Orbit), and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's not the best way, but should work

http://rockonflash.wordpress.com/2010/04/17/how-to-do-lasers-in-unity3d/

Debug.DrawLine only works on Scene Window