# Unity3D draw angle between two lines (curved arrow/line)

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

How to draw this red line, between two lines but in 3D space.

Comment: Note, you can and should *include images in questions* here.  Click "Edit" and the "image" button to do so.

Comment: has been asked a thousand times.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16040142/294884  unity *does not draw lines*. use Vectrosity or the like

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `Vector3.Angle`?

Note: this always returns the acute angle.

Comment: I don't need just to calculate angle, I need to draw a line between two lines, like curved arrow, look at the picture i posted.

Comment: have you tried anything? if so, post some sample code because otherwise your question title is misleading.

Comment: I haven't tried anything, cuz i don't know what to try, lel.