# How to draw a line with x length in the direction of the mouse position in unity3D?

Tags: math, vector, unity-game-engine

My question seems rather simple but i cant figure it out myself.

I want to draw a line with a fixed length from my transform.position in the direction where the mouse cursor is.

The things i figured out:

```
var mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
lazer.setPosition(0, transform.position);

// here is where the failing starts. i need to calculate the end position.
lazer.setPosition(1, ?)
```

Thanks A.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [drawing a line following an object in unity c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16039520/drawing-a-line-following-an-object-in-unity-c-sharp)

Comment: i use the LineRenderer to do it. I am just asking for the vector math that will calculate the end position of the LineRenderer.

Comment: Drawing a line one merely draws a very thin quad whose normal is facing the camera (or at least within 180 degress).  [Here's one I prepared earlier](https://youtu.be/58vhvHjk0Ws?t=25s).  All you have to do is ensure the width of the quad is reverse projected from screen space so that the width of the "line" remains constant regardless of the distance from the camera

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the variable `normalized` on either the `Vector2` or `Vector3` class. Something like this will give you a new vector with the same length (magnitude, actually) every time:

```
Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
Vector3 offsetPos = mousePos - transform.position;
Vector3 newVec = offsetPos.normalized * scale; // this is the important line
newVec += transform.position;
```

Comment: You just saved me a lot of headache, spend 30 minutes looking for this Thanks!